# How to find file in same directory using C++?

Tags: c++, file, io

So I am using C++ to try to find a file. However, on my friends computer he keeps the file in a different directory than what I have it in. On top of that, he has a different username than I do, so mine searches C:\Users\Zero\ and his searches something different. Meaning even if he has it in the same directory as me, it won't get found because his pc username is different than mine. The file we are trying to find is a DLL file. And I have no idea how to find it. I tried using fstream to help but later on in the code, this gets called
 `WriteProcessMemory(hProc, loc, dllPath, strlen(dllPath) + 1, 0);` which errors at the strlen because it can't convert it to a LPCVOID. I am currently writing the string as this:
`const char* dllPath = "C:\\Users\\Zero\\Documents\\GitHub\\ExtensionProject\\32-Bit\\Debug\\Extension.dll";`
So I'm trying to figure out how to skip the whole C:\Users\ thing, and I'm wondering, is there any way to just read from the folder that it's currently located in? Because the dll and .exe that finds the dll are compiled in the same folder. If you need me to provide more information, let me know! I'll gladly provide more. Also, I'm pretty new to C++ and I understand that C++ isn't easy, but the easiest method to get this done would be appreciated, but at the same time, I'll take what I can get.

Answer (score 0):

If your library is loaded into the executable as it starts, you can get its location from the library loader (`GetModuleInfo` or something like that).

Comment: I don't believe I do. Let me be more specific: I have an dll called Extension.dll located at C:\Users\Zero\Desktop\ExtensionProject. ExtensionProject is a folder. This folder has the Extension.dll inside of it as well as the ExtensionLoader.dll inside of it. So the Loader and the Extension are both in the same path. When I run the exe (The loader) It tries to find the DLL to push it into a certain process. However, if I don't hardcode the dllPath, I don't know how to make it work. As well as, my friend will not be able to use it since his windows username is different from my own.

Comment: @Zero03 if the loader and the target DLL are in the same folder, then the loader can retrieve its own path via `GetModuleFileName()` and then replace the trailing filename portion with the target DLL name.